# How do I upload node.js files to AWS Lambda and run successfully?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

```
console.log('starting function')
exports.handle = function(event, context, callback){

  var firebase = require('firebase');
  var admin = require("firebase-admin");
  var Mixpanel = require('mixpanel');

  // initialize mixpanel client configured to communicate over https
  var mixpanel = Mixpanel.init('********************', {
  protocol: 'https'
  });

  var serviceAccount = require("productionKey.json");
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "********************"
  });

  function getTotalUsers(){
    admin.database().ref("users").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Total Users:", snapshot.numChildren());
      mixpanel.track('Users Calculated', {
        distinct_id: '9999',
        "Total Users": snapshot.numChildren()
      });
      callback(null, snapshot.numChildren());
    });
  }

  getTotalUsers();
}
```

My question is how do I actually get this working and running in AWS Lambda? I added in the first two lines and the callback because I assumed that is what is necessary for AWS. I'm new to this, but my script works just fine without those elements. I zip up the components, including the modules and package.json and the firebase production key and upload it as a Lambda function, when I test it though it just times out no matter what I change the max timeout to.

What am I doing wrong? I write tons of node.js scripts not too dissimilar from these and I'd love to know how I can get them running on AWS Lambda (scheduled). Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: a few things to check, is the DB that you are connecting to accessible? By default AWS Lambda doesnt run in a VPC, that might be one reason that its timing out.

Comment: @Yogesh_D the DB is accessible, I run the node.js script locally without the first two lines (for aws) and the callback and it works just fine. That's why I'm getting hung up, the script runs like a charm until I try uploading it to Lambda.

Comment: I mean is the DB public? (if its hosted in AWS)

Comment: @Yogesh_D it's a firebase database, not hosted in AWS. the script is just querying firebase using the private keys to access it.

Comment: It's a very common misconfiguration to try to run a Lambda function in a VPC without correctly configuring the function to run on a private subnet whose route table provides access to a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I looked in advanced settings and it's actually set to "No VPC". Do I need to run this script in a VPC?

Comment: Not if it isn't accessing resources in a VPC.  Ah, wait... `exports.handle` needs an "r" at the end.  The convention is **`exports.handler`**.  That, and your code is a little bit inside out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda functions don't run like a script.  They set things up and export a handler function, which Lambda invokes.  The container will often persist, with Lambda re-invoking the handler with everything already initialized on subsequent (but not concurrent) invocations.

Untested, but to give you the idea, a high-level Lambdafication of your code might look more like this:

```
  console.log('starting initialization')


  var firebase = require('firebase');
  var admin = require("firebase-admin");
  var Mixpanel = require('mixpanel');

  // initialize mixpanel client configured to communicate over https
  var mixpanel = Mixpanel.init('********************', {
  protocol: 'https'
  });

  var serviceAccount = require("productionKey.json");
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "********************"
  });

  exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) => {

    console.log('function invoked');

    // google this -- you probably need this set to false, default is true 
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    admin.database().ref("users").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Total Users:", snapshot.numChildren());
      mixpanel.track('Users Calculated', {
        distinct_id: '9999',
        "Total Users": snapshot.numChildren()
      }); 
      callback(null, snapshot.numChildren());
    });

  };
```

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! Thank you!! :)  I had already changed my code from the odd format it was in and changed it to handler, but it was still timing out because the function was not actually ending. Your addition nailed it! Thank you so much man! :)